# 3phase surge suppressor on single phase utility supply

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am using a 3 phase 4 wire surge suppressor on a single phase 240V mains. Is it still okay or will it have some back feed impact on the mains system?

Comment: is your surge suppressor made for Wye or Delta power?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I would think Wye since it says 4 wire.

Comment: @Ben -- three phase high leg delta is also considered a 4 wire system

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel But is that how the surge suppressor is going to be sold/marketed? I'm not asking that rhetorically.

Comment: What voltage was the 3 phase system? I ask as it may not be doing much good at all if out of a higher voltage system.  if the same voltage it won’t be a problem no matter Wye or Delta for standard MOV’s.